# How to find the minor matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I try to implement the method of calculating the minor of the matrix element by the standard method of crossing out the row of the column at the intersection of which there is a selected element

there is matrix

```
[-2  -1   -2]
[ 4   1   -2]
[ 8   2   -2]
```

looking for a minor of a matrix by this method

1.find the largest element in the last row of the first column

2.looking for the largest element, if there is such an element in the array, I get the coordinates of the element

3.then I check the intersection of rows and columns with the element

```
public class Determinant {

    private int n;
    private int max;
    private int x, y;

    public Determinant(int[][] r) {
        n=r.length;
    }

    public int[][] Minor(int[][] matrix){
        max=0;
        x=0;
        y=0;

        for(int l=0; l<n; l++) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {

                if(max<matrix[l][0]) {
                    max=matrix[l][0];
                }//find the largest item

                if(matrix[l][j]==max) {
                    x=l;
                    y=j;
                }//check the presence of an element in the array

                if(l==x&&j==y) {
                    matrix[l][j]=0;
                }//exclude row, column
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

the input is a matrix

```
[-2   -1   -2]
[ 4    1   -2]
[ 8    2   -2]
```

in the calculation process of minor turns

```
[ 0   -1   -2]
[ 0    1   -2]
[ 0    2   -2]
```

on the exit I await

```
[ 0   -1   -2]
[ 0    1   -2]
[ 0    0    0]
```

Comment: Please check out [ask] and [edit] your question to include some kind of question or describe a problem you encountered.

Comment: relate Question https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/39332-minor-matrix.html

Comment: Looking at your code, there is more wrong than just this. Hint: you cannot do all in the same nested loop.

Comment: @Генри it is practical to use more than one nested loop professionally